# FlowRouter - Inserting content to HTML template

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, flow-router, kadira

I'm trying to learn meteor-react, and I have a question about using FlowRouter to insert content into HTML template pages.

Let's assume everything is imported correctly, this is the relevant code:

*routes.jsx*

```
FlowRouter.route('/post/:postId', {
  name: 'posts.single',
  action({postId}) {
    mount(MainLayoutCtx, {
      content: () => (<Post postId={postId}/>)
    });
  }
});
```

*index.jsx - where MainLayoutCtx is pointing to*

```
const Layout = ({content = () => null }) => (
  //code here
);
```

In index.jsx, *{content = () => null}*. Doesn't this mean content is an object literal that has no parameters and outputs null?

But when content is being passed in routes.jsx, it's *() => (/Post postId={postId}/>)* So isn't that content outputting Post with postId passed in as a prop?

How does this match with what index.jsx is expecting?

Comment: There is no straightforward way to pass data from route to template in Flow-Router, take a look on [flow-router-extra](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/flow-router), this is extended fork of FR, with hook to pass data from router to templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `content` is a function literal with no input parameters in both cases, and it returns a new React component. (`null` is a valid React component, too.)

```
content: () => (<Post postId={postId}/>)
```

In this case `postId` is not a parameter, but a closure variable. The closure object gets created runtime embedding the value of `postId` when that is of code is reached.

In `index.jsx` your layout expects a function with no parameters that returns a React component, and that's exactly what `content` is. And when you call `content()`, it creates a new `Post` component, and passes the `postId` from its closure object as props.